Is there a way to assign all of the parameters being passed in to a Function to a "variable, list dictionary" etc.?
Lets say I have this function below.  As you can see I have a lot of parameters being passed in.  I then want to send all of those parameters to another function.
public DataTable DataTableFunction1(string CoTypeRegular,string CoTypeBlanket,string CoStatus,string CoLineReleaseStat,string PrintItemCustItem,
            string PrintOrderText,string PrintStandardOrderText,string PrintCompanyName,string DisplayDate,string DateToAppear,string DateToAppearOffset,
            string PrintBlanketLineText,string PrintBlanketLineDes,string PrintLineReleaseNotes,string PrintLineReleaseDes,string PrintShipToNotes,
            string printBillToNotes,string PrintPlanningItemMaterials,string IncludeSerialNumbers,string PrintEuroValue,string PrintPrice,string Sortby,
            string OrderStarting,string OrderEnding,string SalespersonStarting,string SalespersonEnding,string OrderLineStarting,string OrderReleaseStarting,
            string OrderLineEnding,string OrderReleaseEnding,string ShowInternal,string ShowExternal,string PrintItemOverview,string DisplayHeader,
            string ConfigDetails,string TaskId,string pSite,string PrintDrawingNumber,string PrintTax,string PrintDeliveryIncoTerms,string PrintEUCode,
            string PrintOriginCode,string PrintCommodityCode,string PrintCurrencyCode,string PrintHeaderOnAllPages,string PrintEndUserItem)
{


    return DataTableFunction2(this.Context.Commands,  CoTypeRegular,  CoTypeBlanket,  CoStatus,  CoLineReleaseStat,  PrintItemCustItem,
             PrintOrderText,  PrintStandardOrderText,  PrintCompanyName,  DisplayDate,  DateToAppear,  DateToAppearOffset,
             PrintBlanketLineText,  PrintBlanketLineDes,  PrintLineReleaseNotes,  PrintLineReleaseDes,  PrintShipToNotes,
             printBillToNotes,  PrintPlanningItemMaterials,  IncludeSerialNumbers,  PrintEuroValue,  PrintPrice,  Sortby,
             OrderStarting,  OrderEnding,  SalespersonStarting,  SalespersonEnding,  OrderLineStarting,  OrderReleaseStarting,
             OrderLineEnding,  OrderReleaseEnding,  ShowInternal,  ShowExternal,  PrintItemOverview,  DisplayHeader,
             ConfigDetails,  TaskId,  pSite,  PrintDrawingNumber,  PrintTax,  PrintDeliveryIncoTerms,  PrintEUCode,
             PrintOriginCode,  PrintCommodityCode,  PrintCurrencyCode,  PrintHeaderOnAllPages,  PrintEndUserItem);


}

In other words can I do something like this for DataTableFunction2?
return DataTableFunction2(this.Context.Commands,  params string[] args);

Again I am just using "params string[] args" as an example here so you can see what I am trying to do.
At this point I did not try anything as I have not been able to find a solution to this question.

why use so many arguments? If lots of data needs to be passed then create a struct to pass the parameters

The refactoring you're looking for is called "Introduce Parameter Object".

Should all of these parameters really be strings?  My guess is that you should think about your data model, what types you should use, and how the values are related to each other. Something named DisplayDate should probably be a DateTime. If you have several parameters named Print*, chances are they should be part of the same object. Ideally you should end up with a few, higher level, paramters that can be easily forwarded to the next method.

fair question on why so many arguments, but it is how C# integrates with Syteline when you are writing an assembly to wrap one of the built in stored procedures.

"Should all of these parameters really be strings? " another fair question but, yes, that is how Syteline has these set up.  So I am at the mercy of that system.

I am a little confused as to why the question was down voted?  If you are going to down vote the question, at least comment to explain your vote.

The recommended solution when you have many parameters is to be to have a class/struct that holds all of those values. It can reduce repetition as well as provide the structure given by a Dictionary, and on top of that, it ensures that you have the data you need, no more, no less - no need to check that every key is there at runtime, it's all handled at compile time.
Consider the following:
class DataTableData
{
    string CoTypeRegular { get; set; }
    string CoTypeBlanket { get; set; }
    string CoStatus { get; set; }
    string CoLineReleaseStat { get; set; }
    string PrintItemCustItem { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

DataTable DataTableFunction1(DataTableData data) 
{
    DataTableFunction2(this.Context.Commands, DataTableData data);
}

